# Doctrine2 LEFT JOIN exception

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've got a problem with Symfony/Doctrine2 doing `SQL` statement with two entites:

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('s')
    ->from('basecomProductionWorkflowBaseBundle:SubprocessData', 's')
    ->leftJoin('basecomProductionWorkflowBaseBundle:ReleaseDay', 'r', Expr\Join::WITH, 'r.id = s.releaseDay')
    ->where(
            $qb->expr()->andX(
                    $qb->expr()->eq('r.date', ':date'),
                    $qb->expr()->isNotNull('r.edition')
            )
    )
    ->setParameter('date', $date);
```

I got the following error message:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 124 near 'r WITH r.id =': Error: Identification Variable basecomProductionWorkflowBaseBundle:ReleaseDay used in join path expression but was not defined before.
```

PS: Both tables have no relation to each other (it's a workaround fixing another problem). I've tested the same statement in phpmyadmin.

Comment: Why did you choose `Expr\Join::WITH` here instead of `Expr\Join::ON`? The latter seems to be more appropriate here.

Comment: i was trying to solve my problem using different types. but always the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```php
->leftJoin('s.releaseDay', 'r')
```

You could also simplify the conditions this way:

```php
->where('r.date = :date')
->andWhere('r.edition IS NOT NULL')
```

or:

```php
->where('r.date = :date AND r.edition IS NOT NULL')
```

Comment: i forgot to say that both tables have no relation to each other. your suggestion above fails => 0 results. same statement in phpmyadmin returns the number of results i want to have.

Comment: don't know why but now it's working. i tried to build some relations between both tables. the question how to do a left join on two independent tables with no relation is still left but the problem is fixed. thx

Answer (score 0):

¿What Expr class are you using?
I choose incorrectly the Expr class some days ago and throw me same exception.

Try:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr;
```

Comment: i'm using the same Expr class :-/.